# quarkus.flyway.placeholders override via enviroment variable

Tags: java, quarkus

In my application.yaml I have:

```
quarkus:
   flyway:
      datasource:
         placeholders:
            some_property: some_value
```

I was hoping that running the app with an environment variable:

```
QUARKUS_FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS=some_property=diff_value
```

would override the one from `application.yaml` (much like a Spring's EnvironmentPostProcessor would), but this is not the case.

Using *just* the environment variable works, but then I don't have a "default", if one is not specified.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
quarkus:
   flyway:
      datasource:
         placeholders:
            some_property: ${SOME_PROPERTY:some_value}
```

where `SOME_PROPERTY` is an environment variable.